# Does Javascript code pass referrer traffic

Tags: javascript

I have a site **website-A.com** where i added a Javascript code from another site **website-B.com**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="website-B.com/js/file.js"></script>
```

My issue is: can the **website-B.com** through this JS code see the **REFERRER** traffic that comes to my website?

i.e. Email marketing > customers click on the link > they go to my website **website-A.com** which has that JS code in the source ; can **website-B.com** see that the traffic came from email marketing?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh I might have misunderstood.. Are you concerned about some traces that would be sent to their server through the request, eg in the Referrer HTTP header, or if **the code** executed from the script can access similar information, e.g through `document.referrer`? If the latter, that really doesn't matter from where the script is being loaded when it's executed, it has all the same rights than a local script.

Comment: To be more clear, I am concerned that website-B.com through the JS code can see where the traffic comes from. this JS code that I am using is hosted on their website-B.com website as you can see, it is more of a form that loads from their website onto my site website-A.com.
So, their form loads through that JS file , but i am concerned if they can see the referrer traffic that comes to the page that has the script above.
Does that make more sense?

Comment: Well once again, all you could do from a local script, they will be able to do it too from this script. If you don't trust them, don't load their version of the script, but use one you do control and have reviewed. Because indeed, nothing prevents them to send beacons to their own servers from that script.

Comment: I see, that was what i feared as well. I was thinking to have a script locally that loads their script from my local server... but i don't know if such a thing is possible - i mean a way to still load their script but be in control on my end on what info is sent as referrer traffic

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.refferrer` if it's coming from another page or site, but I don't think that works for email...usually you set the link (in the email) with a query params that can be tracked once it hits the target site/page

ie: `www.your-site.com?source=email`   as the link in the email, when the page loads on your site you check the url for the query params and do whatever you need to do as far as tracking